# How to have grid layout components with different cell heights in Unity

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build a scene in my 2D game which has a panel whose elements are arranged as in this image:
[image]

The `ScrollRect` should dynamically add rows after users provide values to the `InputField`, select an option from the `Dropdown`, and then click the `Button`. This all works fine, except that the viewable area of for the `ScrollRect` has the same vertical size as its siblings within the parent panel.

This happens because the `GridLayoutGroup` of the parent panel requires the child cell sizes to be specified, and if I specify a value which makes sense for the top two panels it is too short for the `ScrollRect`. Putting a `ContentSizeFitter` on the parent panel does not help (also, despite Unity warning against it, there is a `ContentSizeFitter` on the content of the `ScrollRect` since without one the newly added rows will not appear when scrolling).

So my question is:

***what do I need to do to allow the vertical sizing of the children of the top level panel to be based on their sizes, when one child's vertical size will change dynamically?***

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For grid layout you cannot control the cell sizes dynamically . Instead you can use horizantal / vertical layout groups where you can find an option control child size . And as mentioned in above ans add Layout element to child component and adjust the sizes

Answer (score 2):

Both @Programmer and @Salma572 answers are true. If you want that size to be a fixed number or pixels, use a `LayoutElement`. However, It doesn't seem you can use a scale (in percent) or anything else dynamic.

It's a shame but you'll probably need to write a script.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Attach [`Layout Element`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.LayoutElement.html) component to each child GameObject. You can then dynamically change the size of each child GameObject by modifying the [`Layout Element`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.LayoutElement.html)'s [`Preferred Width`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.LayoutElement-preferredWidth.html) and [`Height`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.LayoutElement-preferredHeight.html) variable.

Comment: I tried this but it does not work; the children just retain the cell size set by the parent's grid layout group.

Comment: The function of Layout Element is to do this exact thing. You are probably doing something wrong which I don't know.

Comment: Same issue here. Vertical/Horizontal Layout Group with Control Child Height/Width will allow Preferred Width/Height to affect a child, but Grid Layout Group has no such setting. In both cases, there is no support for proportional sizes anyway, so as MrDos said you'd need a script to set the Cell Size manually... Or as Salma572 said, combine Vertical/Horizontal Layouts, but you'd need to recompute nb of elements per row/column for distribution. It would be nice if Grid had the same options as Vertical/Horizontal Layout!